# How to prevent html text appearing before Javascript code executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

Say my html is this

```
<div class='screen'>
    <p>*A lot of text here*</p>
</div>

<div class='screen'>
    <p>*More text and some images here*</p>
</div>

<div class='screen'>
    <p>*Even more text and an image here*</p>
</div>
```

and right below my html, I have this

```
<style>
    .screens {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    hide();
</script>
```

Now, the Javascript function hide is in an external JS file which I imported in the html file. This is the hide function.

```
function hide() {
    $('.screen').hide();
}
```

Now, when I open up this page, sometimes it works (it hides the text right away so it is a blank page) and other times, the text shows for like one second and then the text becomes hidden. How come it doesn't hide the text right away 100% of the time? would it work 100% of the time if I do

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        hide();
    });
</script>
```

?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to hide them with css: `.screen { display:none; }`

Comment: @JasonP right but is there a way to do it with JS?

Comment: Just a side note: you are missing quotations around `.screen` in `$(.screen).hide();`

Comment: Why would you want to do it in javascript?

Comment: @A.Wolff because this is just a small part of the code, the actual code is huge and a lot more than just hiding text before it appears, there is a lot of other JS code (which I didn't write, I am just trying to fix this small problem).. How come it doesn't hide the text right away though anyways? How come it only works some of the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a wrapper div and give it a `display:none;`. When needed, display it with `show()`

CSS:

```
.wrapper{ display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper>YOUR CONTENT</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrapper").show();
});
```

Or if you just care about `.screen`, change its CSS to `display:none` and the javascript to `show()` instead of `hide()`

```
<style>
    .screens {
        margin: 10px;
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    show();

    function show() {
        $('.screen').show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hm, is there a way to do it without adding any additional classes? How come the hide(); function only works some times in the first place? should it not work all the time?

Comment: I edited the answer. Place the `display:hide` in the `.screens` class if you can't modify the HTML (or just don't want to). The inconsistent behavior you are seeing is because sometimes the HTML finishes loading before the javascript has a chance to run and sometimes the javascript runs before the HTML loads completely. If you are unlucky enough, the js may run before `.screen` is even loaded, so the element would never be hidden.

Comment: hm okay thanks.. but oh man, so even if I do $(document).ready(function() { hide(); }); it still won't work 100% of the time?

Comment: It will. `.ready()` makes sure the document has loaded completely before running the callback function. But that means that you are guaranteed to see `.screens` element before it is hidden. If you want to make sure the element will never appear, you must hide it with CSS, since browsers will completely load CSS files before trying to display the document.