# Contents of multilevel navigation getting displayed while the page getting loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a multilevel dropdown menu in my website. Menu is working fine as expected. But the issue is the contents of the dropdown menu displays in a blink while page gets loaded. I have used a plugin to integrate the menu. Link to the [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mega-Menu-dmenu/). Also working example of the [menu](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mega-Menu-dmenu/demo/xmpl1.html).

I have tried couple of things like, changing position js and css files, version of jquery files. But no luck. I have seen the same issue in their example when I tried to reproduce them( I only realised if after integrating). I had already integrated it into our cms and its too late to change it entirely now, so I am looking to fix it somehow. I am not sure if I can past my working copy here. Attaching a fiddle for reference. 
My actual website is [here.](https://www.astrolift.co.nz/)

Attaching [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/xe9fy7u5/8/) for reference.

```
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-menu">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <a href="#" style="background-image: url(img/logo.png)"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="SubmenuTabs IconHidden">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Tabs</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="SubmenuMega">
                                        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/1.jpg)"></div>
                                                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>   
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/2.jpg)"></div>
                                                <a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="SubmenuMega">
                                        <a href="#">Dolor sit</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="Selected">
                                                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Ipsum dolor</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"></i> Submenu with flyouts</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Ipsum dolor</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="SubSubmenuAlignRight">
                                        <a href="#">Link (flyout left)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lorem</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                    <li class="SubSubmenuInline">
                                        <a href="#">Link (with inline submenu)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Lorem (flyout)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum (flyout)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="SubSubmenuAlignRight">
                                        <a href="#">Dolor sit amet (flyout left)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="SubmenuMega">
                                <a href="#">Mega</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Dolor sit amet (flyout)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="SubSubmenuAlignRight">
                                                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor (flyout left)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dolor sit</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Dolor sit amet (flyout)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li class="SubSubmenuAlignRight">
                                                        <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor (flyout left)</a>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Amet</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="SubmenuMega SubmenuFullwidth IconOnly">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Fullwidth mega</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div style="background-image: url(img/1.jpg)"></div>
                                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Link (flyout)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="SubSubmenuAlignRight">
                                                <a href="#">Link (flyout left)</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div style="background-image: url(img/2.jpg)"></div>
                                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div style="background-image: url(img/3.jpg)"></div>
                                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Apple</a></li>

                            <li class="AlignRight">
                                <a href="#">Align right</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Link (with a flyout submenu)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link with long text in it</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="AlignRight">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="text" />
                                            <input type="submit" value="zoek" />
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                </div> <!-- /container -->
            </div> <!-- /header-menu -->
            <div class="header-slider">

            </div> <!-- /header-slider -->
        </div> <!-- /header -->

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Some text</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>

    </div> 


                        $(function() {
                            $(window).resize();
                        });
                        $('#menu').dmenu({
                            menu    : {
                                border          : false,
                                logo            : false,
                                align           : 'center'
                            },
                            item    : {
                                bg              : false,
                                border          : true,

                                fit         : [
                                    {
                                        items       : null,
                                        fitter      : 'icon-hide',
                                        order       : 'all'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        items       : null,
                                        fitter      : 'icon-only',
                                        order       : 'all'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        items       : ':not(.dm-item_align-right)',
                                        fitter      : 'submenu',
                                        order       : 'rtl'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        items       : ':not(.dm-item_align-right)',
                                        fitter      : 'hide',
                                        order       : 'rtl'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            submenu : {
                                border          : false,
                                shadow          : true
                            },
                            subitem : {
                                bg              : true,
                                border          : true
                            }

                        });
```

Comment: If you were to put the JS at the bottom of `<body>` it would take care of this. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eternalhour/12vfpx6h/3/)

Comment: @EternalHour It actually doesn't. If you click the run button fast enough, you can see the FOUC.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it that way. But in any case, there's also this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614889/how-to-prevent-html-text-appearing-before-javascript-code-executes) and this is probably regularly asked and duplicate question.

Comment: @EternalHour, it was in the bottom of the body initially, and as I mentioned I had tried placing them at different positions, still no luck. Also the link mentioned, I have tried that combination too, played around css. Hence I don't think my scenario is a duplicate of what is mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may hide the menu using css:

```
#menu{display:none;}
```

and include:

```
$(function() {
     $(window).resize();
    $('#menu').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the JS is actually doing the hiding after the execution. You can "hide" the menu yourself by adding, where you style the `#menu`, something like this:

```css
#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, in your JS, add

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").css("display", "block"); // or any other value you use
});
```

If this won't help, try something more radical:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#menu").css("display", "block");
});
```

This should hide your menu when the page is loading, given the CSS styles are placed *before* the menu markup.